# how to handle notifications flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using firebase to send notifications to my app what happens is  that I reserved the notifications in the terminal but it's not shown in my application 
so how can I handle the notification in a widget so it appears inside the application

I'm trying to set state the text message variable so that its value become the notification body instead of null but its not working 
my code is that

```
[import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/aboutus.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/adminpage.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/changePassword.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/homepage.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/logout.dart';
import 'package:idb/pages/newsPage.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class NotificationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _NotificationsPageState createState() => _NotificationsPageState();
}

class _NotificationsPageState extends State<NotificationsPage> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _messaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
//String testMessage;
  Map<String, dynamic> testMessage;

  void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners() {
    if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();
    _messaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('notification token $token');
    });

    _messaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        //  print('message ${message}');

        setState(() {
          testMessage = message\['notification'\]\['body'\];
          print('testMessage ${testMessage}');
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        //              print('message ${message}');

        //print('on resume ${message\['notification'\]\['body'\]}');

        setState(() {
          String testMessage = message\['notification'\]\['body'\];
          print('testMessage onResume ${testMessage}');
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        //                 print('message ${message}');

        // print('on launch $message');

        setState(() {
          String testMessage = message\['notification'\]\['body'\];
          print('testMessage onLaunch ${testMessage}');
        });
      },
    );
  }

  void iOS_Permission() {
    _messaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _messaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }

  int _cIndex = 1;
  void _incrementTab(index) {
    setState(() {
      _cIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(children: <Widget>\[
          new Container(
            child: new DrawerHeader(
              child: Image.asset('assets/t.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => AdminPage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
            title: Text('My Cards'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.message),
            title: Text('News'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => NewsPage()),
              );
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.info),
            title: Text('About Us'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AboutUs()),
              );
            },
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
            title: Text('Change Password'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => ChangePassword()),
              );
            },
          ),
          Logout(),
        \]),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Notifications',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey\[100\],
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            '$testMessage',
            style:
                new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        fixedColor: Colors.orange,
        currentIndex: _cIndex,
        //fixedColor: Colors.grey\[100\],

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: \[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            title: Text('Home',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                )),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            title: Text('Notifications',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                )),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.message,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            title: Text('News',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                )),
          ),
        \],
        onTap: (index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AdminPage()),
            );
          }

          if (index == 1) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => NotificationsPage()),
            );
          }

          if (index == 2) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NewsPage()),
            );
          }
          _incrementTab(index);

          // _incrementTab(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();
  }
}
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M7OD.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M7OD.png)

Comment: first of all, `String testMessage` redeclares the variable in current closure. You should use just `testMessage` as declared at the top. Also, I'm not sure whether you actually have this in the code or it's some formatting error - in `message\['notification'\]\['body'\]` slashes are not needed. Use just `message['notification']['body']`. You also would want to check the structure of `message`, whether it indeed has `notification` object and `body` in it. Let me know if these notes help.

Comment: String testMessage solved the problem ... thank you!!!